# Perl "use xmlparser" has an error

Tags: xml-parsing, centos

When I run with a.pl

```
...
use xmlparser;
...
```

I've got an error message as belows

```
@0localhost.localdomain:/home/sylee/work] perl a.pl 
Can't locate xmlparser.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at a.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at a.pl line 4.
```

and I've found a lot of solver like this yum install "perl(XML::Parser)".. etc,
But these don't work. Now, I almost gave up.

Would you please help me please how to solve this problem?

My system is "Centos5-64bit"

## update1

a.pl is consist like this

```
#   Load PERL libraries
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

use strict;
use warnings;

use lib 'bin/lib';                     # Collapse namespace 'lib::'
use xmlparser;                         # Load the XML parser module
```

How to know where correct "use lib 'bin/lib';"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does not sound like the name of the perl module.

Try:

```
use XML::Parser;
```

More than anything try reading the [XML::Parser documentation on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/XML-Parser-2.36/Parser.pm).

Comment: Thanks But I think https://centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=21915 is the same problem of mine.

Comment: You might need to install the XML::Parser module on the server. If you are on shared hosting there is likely "perl Modules" item in the hosting control panel. If you have shell access then you can run CPAN from the shell.

Comment: sorry I'mm not familiar with this job, would you let me know exactly what should I do?